# Storing a lot of numeric data in Plone and generating reports out of it

Tags: postgresql, plone, zope

I just installed plone 4 and will learn how to migrate my current xhtml/css site to it. However, I also have a different need to store client numeric data (a lot of it in many cases) that they can remotely access and use to generate reports. Will the zopedb accommodate this, or can I use postgres as a back end?

Answer (score 6):

For tabular data, use a database. You can access Postgres from Plone, using either the (elderly and aging) ZSQLMethods of Zope, or by using python code and custom code.

The latter is not that hard or daunting, but it does require that you read up on how to create a custom package for Plone. Personally, I'd use SQLAlchemy to integrate the database into Plone views.

Comment: +1. Also, note that the issue isn't the quantity of data. It's the type. The ZODB is great for modeling hierarchy, and particularly good for thinking about security and hierarchy at the same time. It's also a good fit for subclassing something as vague as a document. But if your data lends itself to relational modeling and needs to be accessed by relational methods, put it into relational DB.

In short, use the right tool for the data model rather than adapting your data model to the tool.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example case how we do it.

We run a big Plone site with 4000 users and 80000 data records (content items). The data is primarily stored in ZODB. You can easily scale ZODB as long it fits to your server memory. IF your data set is < 32 GB, no problem with the current hardware.

For the reporting purposes ZODB is no good, because all reporting tools assume (My)SQL backend. So we have duplicate data from Plone to MySQL on Archetypes content on modified event. Then the reports are done having views in Plone which use Python and R reporting language without too many bindings to Plone (it's generic Python code, not specific to Plone).

However, the primary data storage is still ZODB due to permissions, roles and such issues which Plone + ZODB handles nicely and automatically for you.

Duplication to MySQL can be handled by hand or using add-ons like http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ore.contentmirror